# How to add metadata for jstree on select_node event

Tags: javascript, jstree

How to add metadata for jstree on `select_node` event. This is how I am trying to add:

```
$.ajax({            
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/assessment/getassess',
    dataType : 'json',          
    success : function(jsonData) {
        $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
            "themes" : {
                "theme" : "classic",
                "dots" : true,
                "icons" : true,
                "url" : "/css/themes/classic/style.css"
            },
            "json_data" : jsonData,
            "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu"],
            "contextmenu" : {
                items : createMenu
            }
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
            $(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree").description = "Size: 45units"; 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you done some research?

Comment: Yes.. I did. When I use alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id")); on select_node of a node it shows the proper value but when I try to assign something to it. It doesn't work

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It is hard to help/troubleshoot your issue from the line of code above alone. I think you should enrich your question more - take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
            $(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree").description = "Size: 45units"; 
            });

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function incorrectly.

You **don't** assign values to the results of the `$.data()` function, and have it be automagically saved.

What you want to do is change this line,

```
$(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree").description = "Size: 45units";
```

to this,

```
// On the next line, we use "|| {}" because if the data attribute is unassigned, we want to start with a default empty object.
var jstreeData = $(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree") || {};

// assign the property(ies)/value(s) you want.
jstreeData.description = "Size: 45units";

// finally, reassign your modified object back to the data attribute.
$(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree", jstreeData);
```

---

If the data attribute consist of an object, you want to:

1. Cache the object;
2. Modify the cached object;
3. Save/assign the modified cached object back to the data attribute.

Lastly, to modify a `data` attribute, you want to use the `$.data( key, value )` function overload.

Comment: I am sorry for the long gap. But that code didn't work for me.

Comment: @user30081989 Are you still having trouble? If you found a solution, you should post an answer with it.

Comment: Actually my purpose was to make a http get the metadata attributes and save it in the metadata of the node, since the above ways didn't work for me, I used a global variable in javascript which had the json for the tree structure, so I added a extra attribute to every node object to store the data.

Comment: So you wanted the HTTP call to *send* specific jsTree data as metadata? Your question is definitely less clear now. =\

Comment: Hey the above ways didn't work. So I took a completely different method.

Comment: @user30081989 Sounds good! Feel free to post your solution as an answer, and accept it. This should help others in the future.